# Assistance do- while loop to print a statement x number of times from user input

Tags: c

[image]
[image]

The do-while loop only prints once. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I want it to print the number of times of the user input.

Comment: Please paste your code here instead of sharing it as a screen shot

Comment: Before entering the `do while` print the values of `x` and `y`.

Comment: You should also learn to use a debugger. If you are using Visual Studio you can easily put a break point before the `do while` and inspect the values of `x` and `y`. The problem will then be obvious. As a student you'll get more mileage out of debugging your code.

Answer (score 0):

When the for-loop above it is done, `y` is equal to `x`.
That is why your do-while loop will only execute one time.

If you want it to execute multiple times, you should reset `y` back to 0.

Comment: I declared a new variable 'i' and set that equal to zero. I used the new variable instead of y and it fixed it. Thanks.